# Кодировка PDF файла

Tags: php, pdf

После загрузки сайта на хостин при формирование PDF ( dompdf ) "слетела" кодировка.
На локальном сервере ( openServer ) все работало адекватно...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наличие используемых шрифтов проверьте в `dompdf/fonts`. кириллицу там по умолчанию поддерживает только один. хотя в таком случае там чаще знаки вопросов будут

Comment: @teran, имеются

Comment: кодировка БД по умолчанию, и при коннекте? утф?

Comment: @teran, да, utf-8

Comment: $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');                      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: *{ font-family: DejaVu Sans !important;}